# MQTT.js not working inside the Vite (React with TypeScript) and inside the Next.js app

Tags: javascript, next.js, mqtt, vite

Node version: 18.17.1
Npm version: 9.8.1

I have installed mqtt using:

```js
npm install mqtt
```

It's working there without any problem. Code is as below:

```js
import { useState } from 'react'
import './App.css'

import * as mqtt from 'mqtt'

function App() {

  let client = mqtt.connect("mqtt://test.mosquitto.org"); // create a client

  return (
    <>
      <p className="read-the-docs">
        Click on the Vite and React logos to learn more
      </p>
    </>
  )
}

export default App
```

This is the error showing:
[image]

1. Connecting to MQTT broker from Javascript -> Worked
2. Connecting to MQTT broker from Vite (React) -> Not-Worked
3. Connecting to MQTT broker from Next.js -> Not-Worked

Comment: Please show the code that is not working (and expand the error). Your example code is making an `mqtt` connection, whereas the errors relate to a websocket connection (i.e. MQTT over websockets). I would expect the URL to be `ws://test.mosquitto.org:8080` (as per [the docs](https://test.mosquitto.org/)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not connect with native MQTT over TCP from a web app, the library will automatically convert the connection to MQTT over WebSockets (with the default HTTP port).

But if the web app is loaded over HTTPS then the browser sandbox will not allow insecure WebSocket connections,it must be Secure WebSocket.

Change the broker URL to start with `wss://` instead of `mqtt://` and ensure that the correct port is used.