# Connecting mqtt.js client to local hivemq broker running in docker fails

Tags: docker, mqtt, hivemq, mqtt.js

I'm trying to establish a connection from my angular application via mqtt.js client to my local hivemq broker running on docker with the following connection details:

```
const options: IClientOptions = {
  host: 'mqtt://0.0.0.0',
  port: 1883,
  clientId: 'myclient',
  username: 'myuser',
  password: '',
  path: "/mqtt"
};
this.client = mqtt.connect(options);
```

Connecting fails as in the console is logged: "WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:1883/mqtt' failed:" but with no reason why.

Docker runs:

```
MVy2P: no members discovered after 2001 ms: creating cluster as first member
No user for HiveMQ Control Center configured. Starting with default user
Starting HiveMQ Control Center on address 0.0.0.0 and port 8080
Control Center Audit Logging started.
Started HiveMQ Control Center in 203ms
Starting TCP listener on address 0.0.0.0 and port 1883
Starting Websocket listener on address 0.0.0.0 and port 8000
Started TCP Listener on address 0.0.0.0 and on port 1883.
Started Websocket Listener on address 0.0.0.0 and on port 8000.
Started HiveMQ in 8108ms
```

Using hivemq client I can establish a connection in my backend (Java/Spring). So only the frontend client fails.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MQTT.js not working inside the Vite (React with TypeScript) and inside the Next.js app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77255316/mqtt-js-not-working-inside-the-vite-react-with-typescript-and-inside-the-next)

Comment: still not working. changed to wss://

Comment: You will need to use `ws://` (one `s`) unless you have configured hive to use [TLS](https://github.com/hivemq/hivemq-community-edition/wiki/Security#what-is-tls)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`0.0.0.0` is a shortcut to tell a server to listen on all available interfaces, it is meaningless to use it as a address a client should connect to.

Assuming the container has mapped it's ports to the host machine you should be able to use the address `localhost` for a client running on the host machine. If you are trying to connect from another container, then you will either need to use the external IP of the host machine, the host machine's IP address on the docker bridge or the IP address of the broker container

Comment: Thank you for your input!
my angular app starts on localhost:4200 and the broker is running in docker. 
When I start the docker container it says:
"Getting bind address from container hostname
set bind address from container hostname to 172.17.0.2"
But using this adress doesnt work either.

Comment: As this is a web app you must contact to port 8000 not 1883 as web apps can only connect to MQTT over WebSockets

Comment: I found the problem. I did not bind port 8000 in docker. Now it works. Thank you!